# How can I change the ordering of mapped URLs in Spring MVC?

Tags: spring-mvc

I'm running Spring MVC 3.x and I have one Controller with *RequestMapping* annotations (**DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping**) and I have one **ServletForwardingController** with some additional mappings via **SimpleUrlHandlerMapping**. When I boot up my application, I see the following:

```
...
13:24:17,747 INFO  [DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping] Mapped URL path [/{query}] onto handler [com.foo.controllers.BarController@1b20a36]
13:24:17,997 INFO  [SimpleUrlHandlerMapping] Root mapping to handler [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.ParameterizableViewController@598535]
13:24:18,044 INFO  [SimpleUrlHandlerMapping] Mapped URL path [/spring*.ftl] onto handler [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.ServletForwardingController@56eb62]
13:24:18,044 INFO  [SimpleUrlHandlerMapping] Mapped URL path [/shared-resources/**] onto handler [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.ServletForwardingController@56eb62]
...
```

My BarController is of course catching all requests (like /spring_en_US.ftl), but I want it to be tried last. In other words, I want the **SimpleUrlHandlerMapping** to take priority over the **DefaultAnnotationHandlerMappings** in my application.

Comment: Or you could use [this project](https://github.com/bclozel/springmvc-router) for a file-based routes configuration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best solution I found was to replace **mvc:annotation-config** with explicit **DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping** and **AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter** bean configuration. I was then able to set the *order* property on both **SimpleUrlHandlerMapping** (order = 0) and **DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping** (order = 1). This set the priority of the handlers as I needed.

I tried to reorder **mvc:annotation-config** below **SimpleUrlHandlerMapping**, but it didn't change the handler priority as needed.

Answer (score 0):

`DispatcherServlet` should consult the various `HandlerMapping` beans in the order in which they're declared in the beans file. The first one that says "yes, I have a mapping for that" gets the prize.

If you're manually declaring a `SimpleUrlHandlerMapping` and `DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping`, then make sure they're in the right order.

If you're not declaring them yourself, then Spring will use the defaults, which is a `BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping` followed by a `DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping`.