# Solved : Static Resources Springboot (2.6.3) and Vaadin (23.2.5) not served in production

Tags: java, spring-boot, vaadin

I've updated my springboot project libraries:

Vaadin: 23.0.10 -> 23.2.5 (I think here is the problem)

Since then, the application doesn't serve static resources like images.
I could validate, that

- the project structure dosn't change (static files under /src/main/resources/META-INF/resources as documented in [Vaadin documentation][1])
- the resulting jar file structure dosn't change (static files are still under /META-INF/resources)

In the log I could locate the following mismatch between the file structure and the resource path:

```
TRACE o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.traceDebug - GET "/images/countries/de.png", parameters={}, headers={masked} in DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
TRACE o.s.w.s.h.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping.getHandler - Mapped to HandlerExecutionChain with [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.ServletForwardingController@9cd25ff] and 1 interceptors
TRACE o.s.w.s.m.ServletForwardingController.prepareResponse - Applying default cacheSeconds=-1
DEBUG o.a.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.log -   Returning non-STM instance
DEBUG o.a.c.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.log - getResource(META-INF/VAADIN/webapp/images/countries/de.png)
DEBUG o.a.c.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.log -   --> Resource not found, returning null
```

So I'ts quite clear, that the application searches the media in a different folder now.

Can someone hint me,

1. where the resources have to be placed in the jar file? Should I modify a maven step?
2. how can i implement and register a delegator/interceptor for this resource loading mechanism? (Just for debugging/logging reasons - because this is not the first time of this problem)

**[1st Update - 18.11.2022]**

After a small break, I spend more time on this.
I have continued the approach of Simon Martinelli. I used the demo app from start.vaadin.com and started it in ProductionMode. I copied the image "empty-plant.png" in my project into the same folder, where my other static resources resides.

Below are the logs and the difference.

```
Vaadin-Demo-App:
app.jar\META-INF\resources\images\empty-plant.png
10:52:03.952 [http-nio-8080-exec-5] TRACE o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.traceDebug:116 - GET "/images/empty-plant.png", parameters={}, headers={masked} in DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
10:52:03.953 [http-nio-8080-exec-5] TRACE o.s.w.s.h.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping.getHandler:519 - Mapped to HandlerExecutionChain with [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.ServletForwardingController@58d6b7b9] and 1 interceptors
10:52:03.953 [http-nio-8080-exec-5] TRACE o.s.w.s.m.ServletForwardingController.prepareResponse:405 - Applying default cacheSeconds=-1
10:52:03.953 [http-nio-8080-exec-5] DEBUG o.a.c.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.log:173 - getResource(META-INF/VAADIN/webapp/images/empty-plant.png)
10:52:03.953 [http-nio-8080-exec-5] DEBUG o.a.c.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.log:173 -   Delegating to parent classloader org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader@7e32c033
10:52:03.954 [http-nio-8080-exec-5] DEBUG o.a.c.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.log:173 -   --> Resource not found, returning null
10:52:03.978 [http-nio-8080-exec-5] DEBUG o.a.c.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.log:173 - getResource(META-INF/resources/images/empty-plant.png)
10:52:03.978 [http-nio-8080-exec-5] DEBUG o.a.c.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.log:173 -   Delegating to parent classloader org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader@7e32c033
10:52:03.978 [http-nio-8080-exec-5] DEBUG o.a.c.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.log:173 -   --> Returning 'jar:file:/C:/Users/#############/Desktop/my-app/my-app/target/app.jar!/META-INF/resources/images/empty-plant.png'
10:52:03.982 [http-nio-8080-exec-5] TRACE o.s.w.s.m.ServletForwardingController.handleRequestInternal:143 - Forwarded to servlet [springServlet] in ServletForwardingController 'vaadinForwardingController'
10:52:03.982 [http-nio-8080-exec-5] TRACE o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult:1156 - No view rendering, null ModelAndView returned.
10:52:03.982 [http-nio-8080-exec-5] DEBUG o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.logResult:1131 - Completed 304 NOT_MODIFIED, headers={masked}



My App 
app.jar\META-INF\resources\images\empty-plant.png
10:57:04.617 [http-nio-127.0.0.1-32152-exec-9] TRACE o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.traceDebug:116 - GET "/images/empty-plant.png", parameters={}, headers={masked} in DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
10:57:04.617 [http-nio-127.0.0.1-32152-exec-9] TRACE o.s.w.s.h.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping.getHandler:519 - Mapped to HandlerExecutionChain with [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.ServletForwardingController@790174f2] and 1 interceptors
10:57:04.620 [http-nio-127.0.0.1-32152-exec-9] TRACE o.s.w.s.m.ServletForwardingController.prepareResponse:405 - Applying default cacheSeconds=-1
10:57:04.621 [http-nio-127.0.0.1-32152-exec-9] DEBUG o.a.c.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.log:173 - getResource(META-INF/VAADIN/webapp/images/empty-plant.png)
10:57:04.621 [http-nio-127.0.0.1-32152-exec-9] DEBUG o.a.c.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.log:173 -   Delegating to parent classloader org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader@7eda2dbb
10:57:04.622 [http-nio-127.0.0.1-32152-exec-9] DEBUG o.a.c.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.log:173 -   --> Resource not found, returning null
10:57:04.676 [http-nio-127.0.0.1-32152-exec-9] TRACE o.s.w.s.m.ServletForwardingController.handleRequestInternal:143 - Forwarded to servlet [springServlet] in ServletForwardingController 'vaadinForwardingController'
10:57:04.676 [http-nio-127.0.0.1-32152-exec-9] TRACE o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult:1156 - No view rendering, null ModelAndView returned.
10:57:04.676 [http-nio-127.0.0.1-32152-exec-9] DEBUG o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.logResult:1131 - Completed 200 OK, headers={masked}
```

I think here is something wrong with the ServletForwardingController, isn't it?

**[2nd Update - 18.11.2022]**

Removing the @EnableWebMvc Annotation solves it.

[1]: https://vaadin.com/docs/latest/advanced/loading-resouWie rces#resource-cheat-sheet

Comment: This all seems to be correct. How are you loading the image?

Comment: Is this problem happening before or after user logs in?

Comment: @SimonMartinelli: I'm loading the images this way: 

new Image("images/countries/" + strCountry + ".png", "flag for " + strlanguage);

Comment: @TatuLund: No. This problem is before and after logging in. In the log is a hint from spring-security, that this url is not secured - this is correct too. FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal - No security for GET /images/countries/de.png

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem. Just created a new project on https://start.vaadin.com with an AboutView where an image is loaded the same way as you do

Comment: @SimonMartinelli Thx a lot for your support. Can you see the same loader class (WebappClassLoaderBase) in your trace log? Perhaps is my DispatcherServlet misconfigured - but I don't know why or how. ;-)

Comment: In my project (23.2.6) the static resources (ok.png and other images) are in the src/main/resources/META-INF/resources/img/ok.png and I'm loading from Java like this: new Image("img/ok.png", "Done");
I'm using SpringBoot 2.7.x .

Answer (score 0):

After my from 18. Nov 2022, I googled a bit around and found this [question](https://%20https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3448467/how-can-i-change-the-ordering-of-mapped-urls-in-spring-mvc). It hinted me to Spring MVC. And I rembered, that I tested a bit around with it.

So in one of the spring boot config classes was an active @EnableWebMvc annotation. This, of course, damaged the expected behavior.